# Loop through name list and if names exist in selection start after last name

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I apologize, this is my first crack at Excel VBA so excuse my lack of knowledge!

[image: My example screenshot]

So I have a list of (currently) 3 names to assign to the days in column A in a repeating order in Excel.

Currently my VBA code allows it to populate the selected cells with the names in a repeating pattern (this part is good), however there are two pieces I need help with.

1- with current code, once it reaches the bottom of the names it checks for the blank box that would end that list and starts over at the tops as directed but it puts a blank cell first (see screenshot). How can I have it put next name without adding blank cell first?

2- I want to be able to (once this gets going)select the entire D column  through what dates need to be filled and:

-check the lowest non blank box

-match to list and set the
   counter to name below that so 
   it continues the name order 
   from the last person who was 
   assigned

This is code I have now:

```
Sub EXAMPLE()
Dim count As Integer
count = 0
For Each c In Selection
    c.Value = Range("X1").Offset(count, 0).Value
    If c.Value = "" Then count = -1 And c.Value = Range("x1").Offset(count, 0).Value
    count = count + 1
Next c
End Sub
```

Sorry I know that was long, I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth reading about arrays, as this task is ideally suited to their use. Your best bet would be to read the names into an array and then build a recurring array whose dimension is equal to the number of rows in your dates column (or selection, or however you want to define the size of the output range).

Code would look a little like this:

```
Dim v As Variant
Dim people() As Variant, output() As Variant
Dim rowCount As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim endRange As Range

'Read the list of names into an array.
'This just takes all data in column "X" -> amend as desired
With Sheet1
    Set endRange = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp)
    v = .Range(.Cells(1, "X"), endRange).Value
End With

'Sense check on the names data.
If IsEmpty(v) Then
    MsgBox "No names in Column ""X"""
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not IsArray(v) Then
    ReDim people(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    people(1, 1) = v
Else
    people = v
End If

'Acquire the number of rows for repeating list of names.
'This just takes all data in column "A" -> amend as desired
With Sheet1
    Set endRange = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    rowCount = .Range(.Cells(3, "A"), endRange).Rows.Count
End With

'Sense check date data.
If endRange.Row < 3 Then
    MsgBox "No dates in Column ""A"""
    Exit Sub
End If

'Make a recurring array.
ReDim output(1 To rowCount, 1 To 1)
i = 1
Do While i <= rowCount
    For j = 1 To UBound(people, 1)
        output(i, 1) = people(j, 1)
        i = i + 1
        If i > rowCount Then Exit Do
    Next
Loop

'Write the output to column "D"
Sheet1.Range("D3").Resize(UBound(output, 1)).Value = output
```